# Error in function: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, runtime-error, jspdf

I have this code that converts html into pdfs using jsPDF. It works great in chrome and firefox, but upon testing it in safari, I am given this message: `error in function: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor`. Here is my code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");
$(document).ready(function () 
{
$("#runpdf").click(function (event) 
{
    $(document.body).width(1903);
    var count=0;
    $("section").each(function()
    {
        $(this).children('footer').children('article').append($(document.createElement('span')).text((count+1)+".").css("float","right").css("font-weight", "900").css("font-size","150%"));
        count++;
    });    
    var pages = $(".page5");
    var remaining = pages.length;
    pages.each(function () 
    {        
        html2canvas($(this), 
        {
            logging: true,
            profile: true,
            allowTaint: true,
            letterRendering: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) 
            {
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', -425, 0, 1450, 800);
                remaining--;
                if (remaining === 0) 
                {
                    doc.save('test.pdf');
                }
                doc.addPage();
            }
        });

    });

});
});
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this safari problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more details with this question, including what scripts you are including and the order they are being loaded.  Which `line number` the error is happening on would help.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I have no idea; I am using safari and I can't find the console where it would say that. All I can get is an alert that says exactly that. I am using a script that is `<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/Blob.js/BlobBuilder.js"></script>` which I'm assuming is part of the problem, but I can't be sure because safari seems to be a bit behind on developer tools

Comment: Bit of an update, I've found the console in safari, but it says the problem is in line 64,(the line directly after `onrendered` which coincidentally has absolutely nothing on it, so I guess that's not much help